# Jenkinsfile from SCM and @script/@tmp projects

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have configured a jenkins multibranch pipeline project and I want to use Jenkinsfile from SCM. The suggested way is to just put a Jenkinsfile into my project. Jenkins will then bootstrap a job by cloning the repo and run the Jenkinsfile. I noted however, that the workspace then contains my project cloned three times: workspace/myproject and workspace/myproject@script, and workspace/myproject@tmp. I'd think that one clone would be sufficient? When I look at the build output, it sais something along:

```
Started by user felix
Checking out git file:///C:/users/felix/git/myproject.git into C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\myproject_local-win@script to read Jenkinsfile
// then all the git stuff..
Running on Jenkins in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\myproject_local-win
// then the pipeline
```

So it clones into @Script to get the Jenkinsfile, and then runs it in a different clone? I can't see this explained anywhere, which makes me feel uncomfortable. So, what's the rationale?

Comment: The whole thing is sort of a chicken/egg problem. What I now read is that if you use github, it will not actually clone anything to get the Jenkinsfile but download it via github API.

Answer (score 1):

[You need to enable shallow cloning of your branch](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002991272-Why-is-my-multibranch-project-cloning-the-whole-repository-on-the-master-) in order to fetch the Jenkinsfile, and then you can retrieve the whole branch using the regular checkout steps.